# Adding two pane tablet layout causes View not found in mobile (less than w600dp)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to setup my baking app such that for a tablet, it shows two pane (2 fragments) layout:

Fragment A = Left Pane: contains the recipe steps listed in RecyclerView and 
Fragment B = Right pane: contains the step details

In the case of mobile (where layout xml set to less than w600dp), I want to only show Fragment A.

Here is the code in my Activity that holds these two fragments:

```
public class RecipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);

        // Instantiate Fragment Manager in charge of fragments associated with this Activity
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        RecipeFragment recipeFragment = new RecipeFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.recipe_container, recipeFragment).commit();

        RecipeDetailsFragment recipeDetailsFragment = new RecipeDetailsFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.recipe_details_container, recipeDetailsFragment).commit();


        }
    }
}
```

The application throws this error when run on the mobile screen emulator:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070081
>   (com.example.bakingapp:id/recipe_details_container) for fragment
>   RecipeDetailsFragment{a70b224 (264e9189-e051-400b-9899-ba42871c2f89)
>   id=0x7f0700

However, if I remove the code that adds the recipe_details_container to the transaction manager, then the fragment will be able to load with no problems.

So my questions are:

1. Can anyone explain what I need to code in this method to account for the case of a tablet?
2. Think I'm missing something in my understanding, some elaboration would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Because the container `R.id.recipe_details_container` does not exist in the "mobile" layout. You should check if the view exists before trying to add the details fragment

Comment: Thanks!  I have fixed it now to check for that view being null at runtime.  However, Even running on emulator tablet (Pixel C), the application isn't picking the layout I set with sw600dp....